# What's the difference between x<<a + x<<b with and without parenthesis

Tags: c++, bit-shift

I want to multiply a number by 10 using bit-shift operators.
To try, I initialized `x = 1`. Then I assigned `x = x<<1 + x<<3`.This printed `x = 32`.
But when I assigned `x = (x<<1) + (x<<3)`, it printed `x = 10`.
Where does this difference come from?
I am using c++11.

Comment: Every language has precedence rules... http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Oh, I see, but then, if addition is performed before, how does it give 32?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at the difference :

```
x = x<<1 + x<<3
x = 1<<1 + 1<<3     // execute 1+1 first
x = 1<<2<<3         // execute 1<<2
x = 4<<3
x = 32
```

and this

```
x = (x<<1) + (x<<3)
x = (1<<1) + (1<<3)
x = 2 + 8
x = 10
```

Answer (score 1):

The expressions in the parenthesis are being evaluated first. Without them, the shift operations are being performed before the addition.

First, C++ evaluates (x << 1) which equals 2.

Then it evaluates (x << 3) which equals 8.

Finally, it adds them 2 + 8 = 10.